# How to Monitor SQL Server Network Traffic

Tags: sql-server, monitor, traffic

I want to monitor the network traffic used by each transaction with Microsoft SQL Server, for example when a query ran on the SQL what was the size of the request & the response as it passed through the network interface.

Are there any tools which do this, especially free tools?

Comment: Have you tried: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/756/find-out-what-queries-are-causing-the-biggest-amount-of-network-traffic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wireshark, filter capture on port 1433:

```
host [your sql server's ip] and port 1433
```

Comment: While Wireshark is perfect to capture the traffic, and can be used for the size calculation there is no way to tie specific packets to specific queries which means that it is not possible to achieve what @babak asked with it.

Comment: @RobertMacLean perfectly possible in a controlled environment

Answer (score 2):

Have You tried the SQL Profiler tool in MS SQL Server?

It's can be found under the Tools menu. To start a trace in it, click `Create new trace` and then select columns you want to monitor, followed by clicking `Run`.

Answer (score 0):

Built in performance monitor can track traffic if you set it up to do so and want to trace when not logged in.

Personally I almost always get by with Sam's suggestion and just watching queries I'm worried about.