# SQL Server Cluster VIP traffic flow

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have searched on SO and on Google to find an answer, I could not. I did not know if my query was correct. The closest one on SO is this one [How to Monitor SQL Server Network Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840436/how-to-monitor-sql-server-network-traffic).

Here is the scenario, I have a SQL Server 2008 cluster and the virtual IP and name for the SQL Server instance. The clients are connecting to the SQL instance in the cluster using the VIP.

Everything works fine, except occasionally some of the clients see timeouts while trying to connect to SQL Server instance (3-4 times a day). That's when I thought I will monitor the traffic between one of such client node and the cluster. When I see the network traffic between the cluster and the client, I see the packets going between the client IP and the IP of the node on which SQL Server is currently running (not the VIP). My understanding was if I monitor the traffic on the client side, I should see the traffic flowing between the client IP and the VIP, not the client IP and the IP of the actual node within the cluster running SQL Server. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to INSTANCE_NAME or localhost when on the server?

Comment: It is a default instance, I am connecting to the SQL server with the virtual IP.

Comment: I did some more debugging. The scenario is that the errors that are happening are not what I thought. I have an another application under the cluster. This application is opening connections to other SQL server instances on 3 other machines and makes some updates based on the messages it receives. This app is dropping the connections occasionally.

Comment: What I learnt part of this debugging is, for out going traffic, the packets will carry the physical IP address of the node on which the service group is running, not the virtual IP. For incoming traffic  you connect to the VIP of the service and that is he IP address in the packets. Thought it will help some one.